# Powerpoint Add-In - saveAsync does not save settings when called outside of Office.initialize

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I'm developing a content add-in for PowerPoint and I'm trying to persist its state when the user reloads the presentation using the `Office.context.document.settings` functions (`get`, `set`, `remove` and `saveAsync`).

However, it appears that `saveAsync` calls made outside of the `Office.initialize` function do not actually save the current settings, as upon reloading of the presentation, only the settings saved during the initialization are persisted.

For demonstration, here is a minimal example of a counter initialized at 1 and incremented each time the page is loaded, or when the user clicks an Increment button:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Counter Add-In</title>

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Counter Add-In</h1>
        <span id="test-message"></span>
        <button class="ms-Button" id="increment-button">Increment</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/core-js/client/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
(function() {

  Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      switch (reason) {
        case 'inserted':
          console.log('The add-in was just inserted.');
          setState('counter', 1);
        case 'documentOpened':
          console.log('The add-in is already part of the document.');
          setState('counter', getState('counter') + 1);
          break;
      }
      $('#test-message').text(getState('counter') || 'NOT FOUND');
      saveState();

      // Callback functions for buttons
      $('#increment-button').click(incrementCounter);
    });
  };

  // Settings/State helpers
  function getState(name) {
    return Office.context.document.settings.get(name);
  }

  function setState(name, val) {
    console.log('Setting', name, 'to', val);
    Office.context.document.settings.set(name, val);
  }

  function saveState() {
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function(asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.log('Settings saved.');
      } else {
        console.warn('Settings save failed', asyncResult.status, asyncResult.error.message);
      }
    });
  }

  function incrementCounter() {
    var counter = getState('counter');
    setState('counter', counter + 1);
    $('#test-message').text(getState('counter'));
    saveState();
  }

})();
```

**counter-manifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="ContentApp">
    <Id>71a1a0ed-6cd0-4a6e-ad2d-015b8a8b43cb</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Test</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="DisplayName" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>
    <AppDomains></AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Presentation" />
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    <VersionOverrides 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="Presentation"></Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources></Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

When inserted into a presentation, this add-in first appear to behave correctly (the counter is incremented as expected and `Settings saved.` is displayed in the console log each time). However when reloading the presentation, and looking at the console log, we can see that the `saveAsync` call in the `incrementCounter` has no effect, i.e. the increments from the button clicking are not registered, but the increments from reloading the page are.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Edit 2018/01/19**

Not sure if you changed something on your end, but today it seems to work perfectly (reloading does not change the counter value)

**Edit 2018/05/23**

The bug came back again without any change from my end.

Comment: Please clarify. When you press the button, do you see "Settings saved" in the console or "Settings save failed"?

Comment: Can you check the `app.js` code you posted? As it is now it isn't valid JS and it's missing the `Office.initialize` event entirely.

Comment: I've corrected the JS code in the main post. Each time I press the button, I get "Settings saved" in the console as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`refreshAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.refreshasync) prior to attempting to read a given value. This will reach the current settings from the document into memory.

Try this:

```js
function getState(name) {
  Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function(){
     return Office.context.document.settings.get(name);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think this function always returns `undefined` as there is no synchronous `return` statement.

Comment: In the page you linked, I read: _"This method is useful in Word and PowerPoint coauthoring scenarios when multiple instances of the same add-in are working against the same document."_ This is not my case for the moment. I've tried to call the function during initialization or before each get anyway, but I have the same issue.