# PowerPoint add-in does not work in Slide Show (fullscreen) in PowerPoint Online

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

We're currently developing a PowerPoint add-in and we have trouble making it work in Slide Show (fullscreen) in PowerPoint Online, which recently caused it to be rejected from the Office Store.

Here is a minimal example which reproduces the bug, based on the [How-To guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins):

**index.html**

```html
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. -->
<!-- See LICENSE in the project root for license information -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Office Add-in</title>

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>

    <!-- LOCAL -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/css/fabric.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m ms-welcome">
   <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/core-js/client/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/office-ui-fabric-js/dist/js/fabric.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#run").click(run);
    });
  };

  function run() {
    return PowerPoint.run(function(context) {
      /**
       * Insert your PowerPoint code here
       */
      return context.sync();
    });
  }
})();
```

**counter-manifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
    xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="ContentApp">
    <Id>71a1a0ed-6cd0-4a6e-ad2d-015b8a8b43cb</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Test</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="DisplayName" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3004/assets/icon-32.png" />
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3004/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>
    <AppDomains></AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Presentation" />
    </Hosts>
    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3004/index.html" />
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    <VersionOverrides
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="Presentation"></Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources></Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

We're serving our add-in using Browsersync as explained in the How-To guide. When I add it to a blank presentation in PowerPoint Online, it seems to work as expected (except for [a different bug when refreshing described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307057/powerpoint-add-in-saveasync-does-not-save-settings-when-called-outside-of-offi)) until I try to go into Slide Show (fullscreen) mode. I see a loading animation in fullscreen for a few seconds then I'm back to the previous editor mode.

Here are the errors displayed in the Chrome Developer Tools Console when trying to enter SlideShow mode:

> Refused to get unsafe header "X-WacCluster"
>
> Refused to get unsafe header "X-SupportSVGInWebGL"
>
> Failed to load https://euc-powerpoint.officeapps.live.com/pods/RemoteUls.ashx: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://contentstorage.osi.office.net, https://contentstorage.osi.office.net', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://contentstorage.osi.office.net' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$37' of null
>           at PPTe.$22.$17a (VM3959 11b10a4995dd8c5f.js:10)

How can we ensure that our add-in works correctly in Slide Show mode?